# How do I split a text file into blocks using Perl?

Tags: arrays, perl, parsing

I have a data file with lines like this:

```
A1 2 3 4 5
B 1 2 4
B 7 8 9
A6 7 8 9
B 1 2 3
B 5 6 7
A3 6 9 7
B 2 3 3
B 5 6 6
```

Using Perl, how do I split the file into a set of arrays (or any other data structure) when the parser hits a `/^A/` please? 
so I end up with

array1:

```
A1 2 3 4 5
B 1 2 4
B 7 8 9
```

array2:

```
A6 7 8 9
B 1 2 3
B 5 6 7
```

etc.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had to rewrite the answer (after rewritten question)

```
@arrays = ();
while (<>) {
  push(@arrays, []) if /^A/;
  push(@{$arrays[-1]}, $_)
}
```

Comment: That should  be `$arrays[$#arrays] `, or ideally `$arrays[-1]`

Comment: Thanks!
$arrays[-1] ... nice touch.

Answer (score 0):

It is at times like this when I wish [`$/`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html) could be more than just a string. Nevertheless, there are workarounds.

One could slurp the file in and process with a lookahead assertion. The example below simply prints each string delimited with `<< >>`, but the basic idea is the same regardless of what you want to do with the data:

```
$ perl -0777 -wE 'say "<<$_>>" for split /(?=^A)/m, <>' file.txt
<<A1 2 3 4 5
B 1 2 4
B 7 8 9
>>
<<A6 7 8 9
B 1 2 3
B 5 6 7
>>
<<A3 6 9 7
B 2 3 3
B 5 6 6
>>
```

Comment: You need the `/m` modifier, or the `/^/` matches only the beginning of the string instead of the start of any line. I've edited your answer.